# Rotate two div simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to rotate two div, I have two div first is grid div(div1) and second one is content div (div2), Now i'm trying to rotate both div simultaneously,
for example In user propectus  see like a page rotate i.e.., page front area(div 1) go back and back area(div 2) appear in front but with animation, I don't no how i will do this please any one help me on this,

I trying this but no help me it rotate continuously.

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/R6fzF/436/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out!!
To rotate div with contents on it

http://jsfiddle.net/lakario/VPjX9/

```
$('#go').click(function() {
    var page1 = $('.page1');
    var page2 = $('.page2');
    var toHide = page1.is(':visible') ? page1 : page2;
    var toShow = page2.is(':visible') ? page1 : page2;

    toHide.removeClass('flip in').addClass('flip out').hide();
    toShow.removeClass('flip out').addClass('flip in').show();
});
```

Comment: Yeah, it is good . actually if you want to use two divs with animation

Answer (score 0):

Try this out ! it will definitely work!

**HTML content**

```
<button type="button" id="go">FLIP</button>
<div class="container">
    <div class="page1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque euismod mauris metus, ac consectetur felis. Cras consectetur, est vel malesuada faucibus, ligula enim suscipit elit, ut ornare quam urna quis felis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    </div>
    <div class="page2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis interdum, odio vel condimentum varius, nibh nunc ultrices velit, vestibulum consequat arcu libero eget nibh. Integer sed nibh velit.
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS content**

```
 $('#go').click(function() {
    var page1 = $('.page1');
    var page2 = $('.page2');
    var toHide = page1.is(':visible') ? page1 : page2;
    var toShow = page2.is(':visible') ? page1 : page2;

    toHide.removeClass('flip in').addClass('flip out').hide();
    toShow.removeClass('flip out').addClass('flip in').show();
});
```

**CSS content**

```
.page1,.page2 {
   color: white;
   padding: 10px;    
}
/* end */

.container {
    position: absolute;   
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
}

.page1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}

.page2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}

.flip {
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(0); 
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-transform:translateX(0);
}
.flip.out {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(.9);
    -webkit-animation-name: flipouttoleft;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 175ms;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(.9);
    -moz-animation-name: flipouttoleft;
    -moz-animation-duration: 175ms;
}
.flip.in {
    -webkit-animation-name: flipintoright;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 225ms;
    -moz-animation-name: flipintoright;
    -moz-animation-duration: 225ms;
}
.flip.out.reverse {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.9);
    -webkit-animation-name: flipouttoright;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.9);
    -moz-animation-name: flipouttoright;
}
.flip.in.reverse {
    -webkit-animation-name: flipintoleft;
    -moz-animation-name: flipintoleft;
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipouttoleft {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(.9); }
}
@-moz-keyframes flipouttoleft {
    from { -moz-transform: rotateY(0); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(.9); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipouttoright {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0) ; }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.9); }
}
@-moz-keyframes flipouttoright {
    from { -moz-transform: rotateY(0); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.9); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipintoleft {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(.9); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes flipintoleft {
    from { -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(.9); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotateY(0); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipintoright {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.9); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes flipintoright {
    from { -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.9); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotateY(0); }
}
```

Comment: Not working, If you provide it in jsFiddle then it good for me

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code and it's working as per your needs. http://jsfiddle.net/R6fzF/437/

There were some mistakes in your code. First being that you didn't closed the div tags. 
div should end like  . 
In your javascript code, you are selecting individual div. Better way will be to assign a common class and then use that class in selector for eg $('.common_class') or you can also use div tag in selector like $('div')

```
$(function() {
    var $elie = $("div");
    rotate(90);
    function rotate(degree) {        
        $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
        $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});                      
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            rotate(++degree);
        },5);
    }
});
```